# Change modal script so it loads on page load instead of button click

Tags: modal-dialog, google-tag-manager

I have the following code that I load through Google Tag Manager, but the problem is that this demo loads a button at the bottom. I don't want that. Instead I want to load this on page load.

```
<style>/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Test message</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

I think I have to replace:

```
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
```

with something like:

```
<script>window.onload = function </script>
```

Could someone help me out? What do I need to complete the above line of code?

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy: You need to replace

```
btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
```

with

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    })
```

or with

```
window.onload = function () {
      modal.style.display = "block";
 }
```

The first code will load the modal on DOM Ready and the second code will load the page on Window load.